# Two different foreign ids for the same table Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

My entity table has the following data:

```
public uint Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public uint EmailAddressId { get; set; }

public uint? LogoId { get; set; }
public uint? CompanyLogoId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("EmailAddressId")]
public virtual EmailAddressEntity EmailAddress { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("LogoId")]
public virtual MediaEntity LogoEntity { get; set; }
```

I want to add `CompanyLogoId` as a foreign key to `LogoEntity`.

I tried the following but obviously got an error:

```
[ForeignKey("LogoId")]
public virtual MediaEntity LogoEntity { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("CompanyLogoId")]
public virtual MediaEntity LogoEntity { get; set; }
```

Is something like this allowed:

```
[ForeignKey("LogoId, CompanyLogoId")]
public virtual MediaEntity LogoEntity { get; set; }
```

Comment: ***WHAT*** error did you *obviously* get ??

Comment: @marc_s the error is that the entity already contains a definition for LogoEntity.

Comment: Well - yeah - you cannot have two fields with the same name - obviously .... so what are you really trying to accomplish here?? Not quite clear yet .....

Comment: @marc_s I have a logo entity that stores the logo info.. i have logoId which i use when getting or saving a logo but i also want to add the ability for the user to add a companyLogo by using companyLogoId and getting/saving the companyLogo in the logo entity.... I am not sure if what i am trying to accomplish in the same entity.

Comment: So would you just have to have a `LogoEntity` and then a second `CompanyLogoEntity` as field names?? Having two FK to a table isn't really a problem at all..... you just cannot name the field the same for both relationships....